# Use single firebase project for different Android App Stores

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics

I want to use Firebase Crashlytics and Analytics an Android app that is deployed on multiple app stores (Google Play, Amazon, ...)

According to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services) those services do not rely on google play services, so it is generally possible.

I would like to use the same Firebase project for all app stores, and then be able to filter for the app store within the analytics UI? Is this possible? I cannot simply add multiple Android apps to the project, because the all have the same package name on each store. (and changing the package name is not an option!)

I haven't found any filter option that makes it apparent that Firebase can filter for different app-stores automatically. Is there any way to do it manually, or do I have to create separate firebase projects for each app store?